# Strictly convex iff norm is strictly sub additive

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

> Show that the closed unit ball in a normed linear space is strictly convex
>   iff the norm is strictly sub additive.

One part is easy strictly sub additive implies strictly convex, but I'm not able to prove the other way.

Answer (score 1):

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set#In_vector_spaces) you have to show that the line segment (except the endpoints) lies  inside the unit ball $D$.

Let $x,y \in \partial D$. Let $t \in (0,1)$. Then

$$ \|tx + (1-t)y\| < |t|\|x\| +|1-t|\|y\|\le |t| + |1-t| = 1$$

which shows the claim.

Answer (score 0):

We have to prove that if the norm $||\cdot ||$ is strictly convex then it is strictly subadditive. So take any linearly independent $x,y\in X$ then $u= \frac{x}{||x||} , v=\frac{y}{||y||}$ are distinct elements of the unit sphere so $$\left|\left|\frac{||x||}{||x||+||y||}u+\frac{||y||}{||x||+||y||}v\right|\right|<1$$
hence
$$\left|\left|\frac{x+y}{||x||+||y||}\right|\right|<1$$
which proves that the norm $||\cdot ||$ is strictly subadditive.